# Stackoverflow Score Observation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I noticed 3 things 2 days ago

[image]

From the image above

1. You can see all scores are missing for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628703/1226894
2. You can also see that https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628939/1226894 has only +15.  The +10 for an upvote on that question is missing.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12623942/1226894 has 7 votes which should be +70, but as you can see it is only +44.

I would like to know if this is a bug, error or if it is a new reputation algorithm I am not familiar with.

Comment: Congratulations on getting 300+ rep in one day. I have never been even close to that!

Comment: @Bo Persson thanks i really appreciate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its because that there is 200 reputation limit earn by the vote

**note : the accept and bounty is not count in rep limit**

here you can see that i reached the 200 rep limit on the so i got the 14 after that no reputation on upvote after that since accept are not count in limit so got the 15

[image]

Comment: +1 for the graphic (wish I could have provided one  :p)

Comment: wow 7 months and am just getting to know this ?? It would have be nice if there was line a notification like `+0` , `red`  where you can mouse over and it would day "200 reputation limit exceeded" +1 anyway for th einfo

Comment: @Baba also i think it should be but it make the problem when it reach on the question or answer already up voted

Answer (score 2):

You went over the 200 cap for upvotes.

You get the +15 for an accepted answer no matter what, but upvotes are capped at 200 per day.

Comment: +1 even if you don't have graphics you has information i did not know about